# 'render_field' tag requiere un campo de formulario seguido de una lista de atributos y valores en el formulario. attr="value": |

Tags: python, django

Alguien sabe por qué aparece el siguiente error:

```
render_field' tag requires a form field followed by a list of attributes and values in the form attr="value":|
```

En esta línea me lo marca; según Stack Overflow es por un espacio que se pone antes o después de =, pero en este caso ya revisé y no tiene ningún espacio así:

```py
{% render_field formset.empty_form | class+='form-row' %}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow, son 2 palabras separadas

Comment: gracias, lo editaré

Comment: @Christian https://plantillasdememes.com/img/plantillas/por-que-nadie-me-lo-dijo-debo-haber-parecido-un-idiota1.jpg

Comment: @DanteS. g3rv4 siempre lo dice en el chat. Hace tiempo no te veo por ahí

Comment: Es verdad, ya no veo muy seguido el chat. Quiza me aparezca mas seguido por alli :D